# Curl is not working on server when calling with post fields

Tags: php, curl

I have a php code for calling an api using curl

```
$username = 'xxxx';
$password = 'xxxx';
$fields = array(
    'field' => urlencode('field_value')
);
$fields_string = '';

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($output);
```

Its working on my localhost but not working on my server.

This is my curl information of localhost
[localhost_curl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFiCE.png)

And this is my curl information of my server [server_curl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em5w7.png)

Curl is working fine if i call a url without post fields but giving me a not found error if I call it with post fields

Answer (score 0):

As you have confirmed the curl is working on your server, It can happen that the request is redirecting (for geographic location of server) and you are not handling it in your curl. Add this on your curl.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

You can enable the debug mode and see what is curl doing. This will help you to understand more about the error (if any).

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM );
```

Use this before curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);

and use curl_error ( $ch ) function to see the curl errors.